# Why is docker login not working with correct credentials?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do docker login on a linux box. I'm using my docker hub username 'undrewb' and the password I use to login to hub.docker.com. Why isnt this working? I'm not signed into a GUI and docker logout tells me I'm not logged in.

```
drewb@workbox:~$ sudo docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: undrewb
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Comment: Can you login Docker Hub with the credentials? https://hub.docker.com/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, changing my password on dockerhub allowed me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Docker uses credential helpers to securely store your login credentials. There might be an issue with the stored credentials. You can try removing them and then logging in again:

```
rm ~/.docker/config.json
docker login
```