# Docker authenticationrequired but docker login doesn't work and pwd/token is correct

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After updating docker on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS I cannot use docker login anymore.

It all started when I tried building an image:

```
gerardo@gzbook:~/workspace/sim-scenario-extraction/airflow-local-env$ docker compose up --build
[+] Running 0/2
 ⠿ redis Error                                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 ⠿ postgres Error                                                                                                                                                                                     0.2s
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": authenticationrequired
```

then I tried logging in, and while I was able to log into artifactory, I cannot login into docker.

```
gerardo@gzbook:~$ docker login -u gerzin
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": authenticationrequired
gerardo@gzbook:~$
```

I've tried both with password and personal access token.
Weird thing is that I'm logged with docker desktop but I see nothing in the `config.json`:
[image]

Here's how my `.docker/config.json` looks like:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "artifactory.ocp-mycompany.com": {
            "auth": "my token in base64"
        }
    },
    "proxies": {
        "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://userandpwd@serverip:8080",
            "httpsProxy": "http://userandpwd@serverip:8080",
            "noProxy": "localhost,127.0.0.1,172.17.0.,.mycompany.com,cc-artifactory.mycompany.net,artifactory.ocp.mycompany.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Can it be something related to the version of the registry?
Docker desktop version: `Docker Desktop 4.16.2 (95914) is currently the newest version available.`

I tried looking on other SO posts, but the ones I find (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994550/why-is-docker-login-not-working-with-correct-credentials)) are relative to errors about the authorization.

I'm positive the pwd I enter is correct and in fact I don't get an "Invalid user or password".

*Can it be something related to that `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`*? I saw my colleague has `"https://index.docker.io/v1/"` in his `.docker/config.json` and maybe with the latest updates something has changed.

Comment: which os u using?  WSL?

Comment: I'm on `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`

Comment: did u try login in browser ?is it fine?

Comment: Yes, I logged in successfully from browser when logging in `Docker Desktop`

Comment: Do you have Uppercase letter in ur username?

Comment: if yes, try with all lowercase, and let me know

Comment: Nope, my username is the same in the image I posted. I've also tried with the email but no luck. Anyway if it was a problem of username or password I should've gotten `“https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/”: unauthorized: incorrect username or password`

Comment: so , i am guessing they updated the format. on docker login try "rm ~/.docker/config.json"  and login again, in docker, try prune and restart again if it works in local machine in first solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256004/discussion-between-elvin-jafarov-and-gerardo-zinno).

Comment: how it went for u?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov not good and I don't understand how I'm logged in Docker Desktop but in the config.json there's no auth field

Answer (score 1):

try to run `rm ~/.docker/config.json` to avoid possible changes.

and run  `docker login` it will generate `config.json` again.